# Using Sapui5 Fileuploader in Sapui5 Table

Tags: uitableview, file-upload, sapui5

I want to give attachment uploading functionality in table format, so that for every employee user can upload separate attachment.

For this I am trying to use `sap.ui.commons.FileUploader` in a column.
It gets successfully displayed but however when I try to upload files and then go to the next page those files remain there itself and I'm not getting blank value in the text area of the `FileUploader`.

Is there anyone who have successfully implemented this?

Comment: For better help it is helpful if you post the code of your implementation that is not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The `sap.ui.commons.FileUploader` is deprecated since version 1.21. You should better use `sap.ui.unified.FileUploader` instead, which has a `value` property which you can set to `null` when navigating away

**EDIT** I know understand you mean pagination. See this working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ed17a6s1/

Comment: Well this i have tried the sap.ui.unified.FileUploader as well, they remain static when used within the table. and do not change their values when scrolled down (or click of next page incase of Paginator mode)

Comment: That can only happen if you did not bind the upload control to the table's model (i.e. bind the `value` property of the `FileUploader` to the corresponding table row property). See my updated answer for a working example

Comment: Hey thanks alot buddy, that was exactly what i was looking for.
However can u please tell me how can i send this table data to backend?
Will it be using deep entity where everything will go at once or using the upload function seperately for the uploaded files? Please share an example....that would be of great help..Thank You

Comment: Not sure what you mean... this is in essence a multiple file upload, which means you should get a reference to every `FileUploader` instance in your table and perform it's `upload()` function separately. If you need to put the uploaded files in the same request as the PUT/POST you are about to perform, I'm not sure how you had envisioned this

Comment: Uploading all the files at once won't be practically possible, as the amount of data would be large which may hamper performance. So i m thinking of uploading the file directly when the user uploads any file in the uploader.
By the way i just rechecked your given example, in that the name of the files are getting changed once u upload different files for two pages, but the files are getting replaced i.e. if u upload "text1.pdf" in first uploader   of page 1 and "text2.pdf" in first uploader of page2 and the come back on page 1 and click on the first uploader u will see the value as "text2.pdf"

Comment: I just checked it myself, but the first uploader in each page just shows the correct file being loaded (it basically toggles between these two files). Am using Chrome. FF gives strange results inside JSFiddle, but outside JSFiddle it works flawless too. you may try it standalone as well

Comment: I checked it again in Chrome, Actually the name of the files being displayed on the textfields are correct but the actual files are getting replaced.
u get to know the file uploaded when u hover on the uploader. So first u upload file1 in first uploader of first page and then upload file2 for first uploader of 2nd page, and then come back to the first page and hover on the first uploader, The name of 2nd page value will appear i.e.file2.
Please check once....Thank you

Comment: Could maybe just a table rendering issue.. The real proof is when you actually upload the files I guess. But so far I have yet to come across a use-case with a file uploader in each table row myself ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Unified FileUpoloader](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.unified.FileUploader.html)

**in XML view:**

```
<sap.ui.unified:FileUploader id="fileUploader" width="100%" 
 uploadUrl="" uploadOnChange="false" uploadComplete="handleUploadComplete" 
 change="handleValueChange" typeMissmatch="handleTypeMissmatch" 
 style="Emphasized" useMultipart="false" />
```

**in Controller:**
On your next page navigation button click action

```
this.byId("fileUploader").setValue("");
```

Note: If you are using this make sure you add & remove **"slug"** and **"x-csrf-token"** as header parameters.

Comment: Actually i am using "sap.ui.table.NavigationMode.Paginator" for the navigation within the table, hence when i try to go to page no, 2 of the table, every other column data gets changed except the file uploader.
The file uploader of the first page shows the earlier files attached but they should be blank for the other employees.
P.S. This is same when using Scrolling navigation method also, the file uploaders column remain static and do not get scrolled.